# Scheduled daily job(using Simple Daily Schedule) with QUARTZ not firing when expected?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz

I need to schedule a job which should fire daily using [QUARTZ Daily Simple Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html). I have gone through the whole documentation and nothing helped me out.

I have the following code:

```
var builder = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithDescription(key + group)
                        .WithIdentity(trigKey)
                        .StartAt(startDate.Value.ToLocalTime())
                        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                            s => s.OnEveryDay()
                            .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                            .StartingDailyAt(
                                TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(
                                    startDate.Value.ToLocalTime().Hour,
                                    startDate.Value.ToLocalTime().Minute)));

var newTrigger = builder.Build();
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(addNewJob, trig);
```

This seems to work with one problem. If I schedule the job for yesterday at 12:10 it will run today at 12:10. However, if I schedule it for today at 12:10 it will nor run today. I tried it a couple of times. Scheduling it at **12** to execute at **12:30** **(thought it might need more time)** but nothing seemed to work. I checked in the DB and the StartTime is correct. I have a hunch that QUARTZ might be setting the job to execute for the day after the job is scheduled.

And currently I am stuck. I know that this can be accomplished with CRON triggers but I need it with the Daily simple scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The `.WithIntervalInHours(24)` is adding 24 hours to the start time and if it scheduled for today it will run tomorrow. Removing it did the trick.